# Convert string to json data

Tags: python, json, regex

I am converting string to json format as below

```
data = """

S3F4
accept reply: true

"""
```

And json data is `[{"header":{"stream":3,"function":4,"reply":True}}]`

I can use regex and search pattern `S3F4` and add to dict.

But is there any better way or in build functions I can use for more generic solution?

Comment: What is the question? Whether there's a better way (better than _what_?) to "parse" a string like `"SNFN accepted reply: true/false"`?

Comment: Is there any conventional way or use libraries like `json.loads` or this is the only way

Comment: How should there be an existing library to parse your custom data format? (If this is not your custom format but some standard, please name the format.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about all the variations of the input string and what is the scope of characters `stream`, `function` and `reply` can have, but here is what you can start with:

```
S(?P<stream>\d)F(?P<function>\d)\naccept reply: (?P<reply>\w+)
```

where `(?P<...>...)` are [named capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping), `\d` would match a single digit, `\w+` would match one or more consecutive alphanumeric (and underscore) characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> data = """
... S3F4
... accept reply: true
... """
>>> 
>>> match = re.search(r"S(?P<stream>\d)F(?P<function>\d)\naccept reply: (?P<reply>\w+)", data)
>>> print(match.groupdict())
{'function': '4', 'reply': 'true', 'stream': '3'}
```